# Crystal packing prediction for simple organic molecules?

Tags: molecular-structure, software, molecular-dynamics

Is it yet possible to predict a simple organic molecule's crystal structure or how the molecules arrange in a crystal without diffraction measurements?

By crystal structure I mean, how would molecules arrange themselves? For example how an amide would pack, how an n-alkyl carboxylic acid would pack? Not partically interested in lattice systems or whether it's a monoclinic or orthorhombic, but more how the molecules would arrange.

Can anyone recommend softwares that can do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/157; https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3554; https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39070

Comment: Molecular modelling? All you need are good force fields. Organic molecules often have numerous solid forms, there obviously is no clear-cut single solution.

Comment: As of 2022, the crystal structure prediction even for simple organic molecules is far from simple.

Answer (score 1):

This 2020 [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c01134) describes one of the largest efforts made so far. They built a software called *Autopack* based on human expert labels and structure data from Cambridge Structure Database. [Autopack](https://ipo.llnl.gov/technologies/software/autopack) is free of cost and can be requested by filling a form and email to request online.